# R parse variable string format into duration

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a simple list of strings that I want to get into a format of the total seconds.

An example list:
`B = c("39.2s", "31m 18s", "9ms")`

i tried `as.duration`, but the "m" character is parsed as a month:
`as.duration(B) [1] "39.2s"                    "81523818s (~2.58 years)"  "23668201s (~39.13 weeks)"`

What can I try so that the varying format of my strings is always parsed into seconds?

Comment: Not bad.  Still need some guidance for "9ms" which should be parsed as `0.009s` but is parsed as `541s`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a duration token for milliseconds which means these values need to be treated as seconds and divided by 1000.  If you don't have months in your string and all `m` values can be treated as minutes, you can do:

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

duration(
  toupper(
    str_replace(
      str_replace(B, "\\d+(?=ms)", \(x) as.character(as.numeric(x) / 1000)),
      "ms", "s")
    )
  )

[1] "39.2s"                 "1878s (~31.3 minutes)" "0.009s"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution.  You could turn everything into seconds and then add the ones that have multiple units together.  Then, turn the seconds values into durations.  Here's a function that does it.  The output is a vector of durations made by`lubridate::as.duration()`.

```r
B = c("39.2s", "31m 18s", "9ms")

to_seconds <- function(x){
  require(stringr)
  ## identify the multiple for minuts, seconds and miliseconds
  mults <- c("m" = 60, "s" = 1, "ms" = 1/1000)
  ## identify all numbers in the string
  vals <- str_extract_all(x, "[\\d\\.]*")
  ## identify all non-numbers in the string (i.e., the units)
  units <- str_extract_all(x, "[a-z]*")
  ## turn the numeric values into numbers
  vals <- lapply(vals, function(x)as.numeric(x[-which(x == "")]))
  ## removing missing values in units
  units <- lapply(units, function(x)x[-which(x == "")])
  ## turn everything into seconds and sum
  secs <- sapply(seq_along(vals), function(x){
    unname(sum(vals[[x]]*mults[units[[x]]]))
    })
  ## turn into duration
  lubridate::as.duration(paste0(secs, "s"))
}
to_seconds(B)
#> Loading required package: stringr
#> [1] "39.2s"                 "1878s (~31.3 minutes)" "0.009s"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could reinvent the wheel using base R I suppose, so that hours and days are handled too:

```r
parse_times <- function(str) {
  
  strsplit(str, " ") |>
  sapply(function(x) {
    s <- list(
      ms = gsub("^.*?([0-9.]+)ms.*$", "\\1", grep("ms", x, value = TRUE)),
      s = gsub("^.*?([0-9.]+)s.*$", "\\1", grep("\\ds\\b", x, value = TRUE)),
      m = gsub("^.*?([0-9.]+)m\\b.*$", "\\1", grep("m\\b", x, value = TRUE)),
      h = gsub("^.*?([0-9.]+)h.*$", "\\1", grep("h\\b", x, value = TRUE)),
      d =  gsub("^.*?([0-9.]+)d.*$", "\\1", grep("d\\b", x, value = TRUE))) |>
      sapply(function(x) if(length(x)) as.numeric(x))
    sum(unlist(Map(`*`, s, c(1/1000, 1, 60, 3600, 86400))))
  })
}
```

Testing we have

```r
parse_times(B)
#> [1]   39.200 1878.000    0.009

parse_times("1d 4h 3m 2s 400ms")
#> [1] 100982.4
```